# How to apply bold for string in html format in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, string

I want to print text in bold using string that prints in compose mail from my app

```
messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<b>Background Information</b>"];
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your needs? Is it a string based on user input, or will it be the same every time? What does composing mail have to do with this?

Comment: messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<b>Background Information</b>];

in composer mail "Background Information", this string  will appear in bold format .

Comment: Are you saying mail composer has that functionality and you would like it in your app too? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have a string that should  be send  to any mail [like a@gmail.com] after sent the mail to respective  person in that mail my  string  should be  in bold and underlined ?

Comment: Can i execite html code to astring in iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
What you could do is use an NSAttributedString.

NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
NSString *yourString = ...;
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(22, 4);

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:kCTFontAttributeName 
                   value:boldFontName
                   range:boldedRange];

[attrString endEditing];
//draw attrString here...

or 

use this code 

 you do not want to bother with fonts (as not every variation of font contains "Bold"), here is another way to do this:

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:"Approximate Distance: 120m away"];
   [attrString beginEditing];
   [attrString applyFontTraits:NSBoldFontMask
                         range:NSMakeRange(22, 4)];
   [attrString endEditing];
```

Comment: i need apply for strings not for labels?

Comment: please read this http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/ for refernce

Answer (score 0):

`NSAttributedString` sounds like the tool you need. In iOS 7, they added support to parse HTML strings with basic markup for styling into NSAttributedStrings. It's pretty easy:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[someHTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:NULL error:nil];
self.someLabel.attributedText = titleString;
```

If you want to add font styling, I found it's best to add a span with a font specified around the text before creating the NSMutableAttributedString.

```
NSString *styledTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family:'%@'; font-size:%dpx;\">%@</span>", someFont.fontName, (int)someFont.pointSize, someHTMLString];
```